# HTML 5 data attributes not calling URL

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I have created a button dynamically with the following code:

```
var del = $('<button/>')
     .addClass('btn btn-danger')
         .attr('data-type', 'DELETE')
         .attr('data-url', file.deleteUrl)
         .text('DELETE');
```

the file.deleteUrl is something like this: `http://somedomain/?file=1411934997-1528.jpeg`, which passes the data to be deleted to a processing script.

This (above) is providing the button with a data-url attribute, and when the button is clicked I'd like a DELETE call to be sent to that url.

However, its not working at the moment, and I dont know why.

in my console the button looks ok, but the call is not being fired when i click the button.

I'm a noob with data attributes and could use some help.

Thanks

Comment: 1st- `del` is a reserved word. 2nd- How are you deleting it? Where is that code? Where is the `onclick` event? Where is everything? What do you mean by "not working"? What should happen?

Comment: Can you add the code where you bind an event handler to the button?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel `delete` is a reserved word not `del`.

Comment: Crap, you are right. Sorry :/ But the 2nd part still applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the Ajax call on the button click:

```
del.click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("data-url"),
        type: $(this).attr("data-type")
    });
});
```

You can also set this code for any `btn-danger` buttons:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-danger", function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("data-url"),
        type: $(this).attr("data-type")
    }).done(function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove(); // to remove the complet row after delete success
    });
});
```

The advantage is that work for any dynamic futur `btn-danger` buttons (the event `click` bubble to the `document`).

Comment: hi Nicolas - that's amazing - thanks - got it bound now - just one other thing - once i've had the DELETE call go through and it returns something, how can i remove that specific .btn-danger?

Comment: You want to remove the button after the DELETE ?

Comment: actually the button is in a table row, i want to delete the whole row (as the image has been deleted and I no longer want the thumbnail available)

Comment: I have added `.done(function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    })` to my answer. Please accept the answer and vote up.

Comment: one issue Nicolas - the table row isnt being removed - not sure why - the response from the server is a json object in the form: {"1411939719-8696.jpeg":true} - i only want to delete the table if its true

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to just add data attributes. You need to attach an .on('click') event that should make an ajax call to the script. The script should return data showing whether it was successful or not.

Once you get success/failure results from the script that the URL calls, you should decide what to do with the element, whether you want to remove it or show an error message to the user.

ADDITIONAL INFO:
If you'll be generating these buttons dynamically, then you'll need to attach the click event to each new on the you create.

Comment: The last line is not true, delegated events (`.on()`) work even on the dynamically added elements.

Comment: 100% true, wanted to add that to my comment. In the worst case scenario, attaching it to the body should always work.